# show another storyboard as the content of 1st tab of TabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uitabbaritem

I have a tab bar controller in storyboard like below:

[image]

I have anther storyboard which I would like to use as the content of 1st tab. Let's call it **Content.storyboard**

**What I want to achieve is:**

I would like the content of the 1st tab of Tab Bar Controller to be the **Content.storyboard**.

**What I tried is:**

I removed the default 1st view controller from **Tab Bar Controller** storyboard and added a **storyboard reference** connecting **from** Tab Bar Controller **to** Content.storyboard, like below:

[image]

**The problem is** , as you see above, I lost the ability to edit the **Tab Item**.

So, what is the correct way to achieve what I want? (That's showing a view from another storyboard as content of a tab of TabBarController)

Comment: where is your Content.storyboard?

Comment: It is another Storyboard file, I don't show in my question because it doesn't matter how it looks like, it is just a storyboard file which I want to show as the content of the first tab.

Comment: ok double click on storyboard reference it will open your storyboard in navigation controller you have to add manually tabBar item

Comment: I double clicked storyboard reference, nothing happens.

Comment: i mean open your Content.storyboard and add manually  that tabbar Item

Comment: without navigationController you can't navigate to another view controller means tabBar1VC -> childCV or tabBar2CV -> childVC

Comment: Are you asking how to set the Tab Label and Icon? If so, can't you simply select the Item in the Document Outline and then edit the properties, like this: https://imgur.com/MIpcoY3  ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue similar to this recently. I ended up moving the navigation controller out of the separate storyboard and into the main storyboard and configured the tab bar items there.

[image: UITabBarController with content provided from another storyboard]

**EDIT**

After some further testing, it looks like the storyboard reference node gets a fake tab bar item. You can't delete it or modify it.

[image: storyboard reference with fake tab bar item]

To provide the tab bar item for the other view controller, go into that storyboard and set the view controllers simulated metrics to Translucent tab bar:

[image: bottom bar simulated metrics]

Then you can drag in a tab bar item from the object library:

[image]

I chose the Bookmarks system icon. you won't see this reflected in the main storyboard, but you will at runtime (and on the child storyboard).

[image]

Comment: But I don't have Navigation Controller. I don't need that.

Comment: Even after so many years, so saved my life and time :P Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using container view

1) Take Container view in your tab

2) Delete added viewcontroller window (Usually come with container view )

3) Add storyboard Reference

4) Drag from container view to storyboard  Reference choose **embed**   option

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue:

Follow the step:

1. Go to your `Content.storyboard`
2. Expand your initial view controller.
3. then -

[image]

4. After that:

[image]